# Are parameters of JavaScript functions declared as var?

Tags: javascript, parameters, var, let

Are parameters of JavaScript functions declared as var?

1. reassignment
   The keywords for declaring JavaScript variables are 1) var, 2) let, 3) const.
   I thought it was **var or let** because parameters can be **reassigned**.

```js
function test1(a) {
    a = 3 // reassignment
    console.log('a', a) // 3
}
test1(3)
```

2. redeclare - var

If declared with let, redeclaration is not possible.

Since redeclaration is possible inside a function, it is assumed that the parameter is declared as var.

```js
function test1(a) {
    var a = 1 // redeclare
}
test1(3)
```

Comment: Parameters are a separate mechanism than `let` or `var`. Just happens that `var` doesn't throw an error with it.

Comment: There are subtle differences (especially when using default initialisers), but mostly yes they work pretty much like `var`-declared variables in the function scope.